# $nin with the $expr

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a query to find if a user `CreatedBy` is in a `SharedWith`. I want to inverse the query to check if the `CreatedBy` is not in `SharedWith`.

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "$and": [
                        {
                            "SharedWith": {
                                "$exists": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "$expr": {
                                "$in": [
                                    "$CreatedBy",
                                    "$Multi_User"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

MongoDB does not support a direct `$nin` or `$not` for `$and` query.

Any idea how to achieve this.

The user document looks like this,

```
   Collection = [
        {"CreatedBy":
             {"_id": "User001",
              "Email": "user@eg.com",
              "Name": "User001"},
         "SharedWith": [
             {"_id": "User001",
              "Email": "user@eg.com",
              "Name": "User001"},
             {"_id": "User002",
              "Email": "user@eg.com",
              "Name": "User002"},
             {"_id": "User003",
              "Email": "user@eg.com",
              "Name": "User003"},
         ]}

    ]
```

Answer (score 24):

[**`$nin`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) is an query operator not an aggregation operator and also [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) only supports the `aggregation` operators not the `query` ones. So, You should probably use [**`$not`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) with the [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) expression
 in this manner

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "Multi_User": {
              "$exists": False
            }
          },
          {
            "$expr": {
              "$not": { "$in": ["$CreatedBy", "$Multi_User"] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```