# Unrecognized expression '$nin' Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am stuck with this query and not sure even what should I google for to find the solution, in this query, I am looking for a client attached to the specific account but if a client has status "avoid" or "blocked", the query should return empty results. This query is working fine if there is no "$nin" expression, but after I put $nin, i get an error:

```
{ $lookup : {
        from     : 'client' ,
        let      : { id: '$client_id' },
        pipeline : [{
            $match : {
              $expr : {
                $and : [
                  { $eq   : ['$client_id', this.ObjectID(meta.query._id)] },
                  { $eq   : ['$account_id', '$$id'] },
                  { $nin  : ['$status' , 'deny' , 'blocked']}
              ]
       }
}

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unrecognized expression '$nin'
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595559/3641067) should help!

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to buræquete, got this solved:

```
{ $lookup : {
                from     : 'client' ,
                let      : { id: '$client_id' },
                pipeline : [{
                    $match : {
                      $expr : {
                        $and : [
                          { $eq   : ['$client_id', this.ObjectID(meta.query._id)] },
                          { $eq   : ['$account_id', '$$id'] },
                          { "$not": { "$in": ["$status", ["deny","blocked"]] }}
                      ]
               }
}
```